# Netlogo behaviour space final command issues

Tags: space, netlogo, behavior

When trying to calculate the squared displacement of my turtle at the end of a behaviourspace experiment (this was done to repeat the simulation many times, not to vary parameters), I get the following spreadsheet:

```
[run number]        [step]      x_squared_displacement      y_squared_displacement
4   10000   0   0
1   10000   0   0
3   10000   0   0
5   10000   0   0
2   10000   0   0
8   10000   0   0
6   10000   0   0
7   10000   0   0
10  10000   0   0
9   10000   0   0
11  10000   0   0
13  10000   0   0
12  10000   0   0
16  10000   0   0
15  10000   0   0
14  10000   0   0
17  10000   0   0
18  10000   0   0
19  10000   0   0
20  10000   0   0
```

i.e. all of the x_squared_displacements and y_sqaured_displacements are zero. Here is the command I am putting into the "Final Commands" part of the behaviourspace box:

```
set x_squared_displacement [xcor] of turtle 0 * [xcor] of turtle 0
set y_squared_displacement [ycor] of turtle 0 * [ycor] of turtle 0
```

When I test the commands outside of behaviourspace, they work everytime, so I'm really stumped as to what the issue is. There is only one turtle in each run of the model (I know its a bit crude and I suspect asking turtle 0 for its x coordinate is the issue, but I can't think of another way of doing it)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe the final commands run after the results have already been recorded? The documentation doesn't seem to be clear on this.

Comment: Do a `count turtles` in the final commands section and see if it still exists. I would personally do this sort of calculation in the outputs (ie "Measure runs using these reporters". If you have BehaviorSpace set to only report at the end (ie uncheck "Measure runs at every step") you should get what you want.